# C - PGM and PPM -dynamically allocated table, image cut in half

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, dynamically-generated

I have a program that works on PGM images. I have to remake it so it also works on PPM images. I am now using dynamically allocated table to store the image in memory. The problem is that it works good on PGM images, but PPM are cut in half. 
[Input&output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk1fP.jpg)
What's going on? These are places which I think are suspicious:

This is how I create the table:

```
obraz->piksele=(int**)malloc(obraz->wymy*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<obraz->wymy; i++)
{
    obraz->piksele[i]=(int*)malloc(obraz->wymx*sizeof(int));
}
  for (i=0;i<obraz->wymy;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<obraz->wymx;j++) {
      fscanf(plik_we,"%d",&(obraz->piksele[i][j]));
    }
    }
  }
  return obraz->wymx*obraz->wymy;
}
```

This is how I save a new file:

```
int zapisz(FILE *plik_wy,TObraz *obraz)
{
    int i,j;
    if(obraz->format==2) 
        fprintf(plik_wy,"P2\n"); 
    else 
        fprintf(plik_wy,"P3\n");
    fprintf(plik_wy,"%d %d\n",obraz->wymx,obraz->wymy);
    fprintf(plik_wy,"%d\n",obraz->szarosci);
    for(i=0;i<obraz->wymy;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<obraz->wymx;j++)
        {
            fprintf(plik_wy,"%d ",obraz->piksele[i][j]);
            if(j>1 && j%15==0) 
                fprintf(plik_wy,"\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

Also the structure of TObraz:

```
typedef struct
{
  int **piksele;
  int format;
  int wymx;
  int wymy;
  int szarosci;
} TObraz;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `malloc` you're doing is the same for PGM (grayscale) and PPM (color image) files. In your results the PPM image is not cut in a half, is cut in 1/3.

First of all, the malloc that you're doing it should be:

```
obraz->piksele=(int**)malloc(obraz->wymy*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<obraz->wymy; i++)
{
    obraz->piksele[i]=(int*)malloc(3 * obraz->wymx*sizeof(int));
}
```

More changes in the file save are likely, depending on your final application.

References of the each format specification:

http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html

http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html